# How to execute and get content of a .php file in a variable?

Tags: php, file, return, file-get-contents

I want to get contents of a .php file in a variable on other page.

I have two files, `myfile1.php` and `myfile2.php`.

**myfile2.php**

```
<?PHP
    $myvar="prashant"; // 
    echo $myvar;
?>
```

Now I want to get the value echoed by the myfile2.php in an variable in myfile1.php, I have tried the follwing way, but its taking all the contents including php tag () also.

```
<?PHP
    $root_var .= file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myfile2.php", true);
?>
```

Please tell me how I can get contents returned by one PHP file into a variable defined in another PHP file.

Thanks

Comment: The non-accepted answer below is the better one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/851773/632951

Comment: **ALWAYS BE CAREFULL**, because if you will use `ob_get_contents()` ,  then you may need to do `ob_end_flush` , otherwises you may have problems, if you use  will use any php `header` command after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [include](http://www.php.net/include) directive to do this.

File 2:

```
<?php
    $myvar="prashant";
?>
```

File 1:

```
<?php 

include('myfile2.php');
echo $myvar;

?>
```

Comment: I know this method already and its working fine, but is there no way other than this?

Comment: @Prashant And what is your problem with this method? It is indented for doing this.

Comment: Actually I was just looking that is there any "return " type method which can directly give me the value. Anyways I adopted @zombat's answer as the method suggested by @harto may have some performance issues, and I can't compromise with performance. Thanks guyz.

Answer (score 40):

You have to differentiate two things:

- Do you want to capture the output (`echo`, `print`,...) of the included file and use the output in a variable (string)?
- Do you want to return certain values from the included files and use them as a variable in your *host* script?

Local variables in your included files will always be moved to the current scope of your *host* script - this should be noted. You can combine all of these features into one:

`include.php`

```
$hello = "Hello";
echo "Hello World";
return "World";
```

`host.php`

```
ob_start();
$return = include 'include.php'; // (string)"World"
$output = ob_get_clean(); // (string)"Hello World"
// $hello has been moved to the current scope
echo $hello . ' ' . $return; // echos "Hello World"
```

The `return`-feature comes in handy especially when using configuration files.

`config.php`

```
return array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
     ....
);
```

`app.php`

```
$config = include 'config.php'; // $config is an array
```

**EDIT**

To answer your question about the performance penalty when using the output buffers, I just did some quick testing. 1,000,000 iterations of `ob_start()` and the corresponding `$o = ob_get_clean()` take about 7.5 seconds on my Windows machine (arguably not the best environment for PHP). I'd say that the performance impact should be considered quite small...

Answer (score 20):

If you only wanted the content `echo()`'ed by the included page, you could consider using output buffering:

```
ob_start();
include 'myfile2.php';
$echoed_content = ob_get_clean(); // gets content, discards buffer
```

See http://php.net/ob_start

Comment: ob_start() is new for me. So, @harto can you suggest me which method will do better according to performance, your method or the method @zombat suggested ??

Comment: Output buffering adds a small performance hit, as there is overhead in initializing and maintaining the buffers.

Comment: @Prashant: I don't have any data available, but I'd guess that the performance impact would be negligible. You could try both methods and see if there's a measurable difference between the two, but I think it would be very small indeed.

Answer (score 14):

I always try to avoid **`ob_`** functions. Instead, I use:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.php');
$content = eval("?>$file");
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is interesting. Can you please share that why you avoid output buffering, and use eval() instead? Your answer will be a good knowledge for me.

Comment: Thanks for the `eval("?>$file")` trick. That's really useful.

Comment: OB_ functions modify the output buffer, and the many other codes in CMS could be using buffer functions indpendently at that time, and it may come into conflict, or clean buffer, or modify it... So,I never touch it.

Comment: If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Answer (score 6):

"Actually I was just looking that is there any return type method which can directly give me the value" - You just answered your own question.

See http://sg.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, Example #5

file1.php:

```
<? return 'somevalue'; ?>
```

file2.php:

```
<?

$file1 = include 'file1.php';
echo $file1; // This outputs 'somevalue'.

?>
```

Comment: This deserves more views!

Answer (score 5):

You can use output buffers, which will store everything you output, and will not print it out unless you explicitly tell it to, or do not end/clear the buffers by the end of path of execution.

```
// Create an output buffer which will take in everything written to 
// stdout(i.e. everything you `echo`ed or `print`ed)
ob_start()
// Go to the file
require_once 'file.php';
// Get what was in the file
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

myfile1.php

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://domainname/myfile2.php");
?>
```

myfile2.php

```
<?PHP
    $myvar="prashant";
    echo $myvar;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all over site use by

```
<?php
$URL = 'http://www.example.com/';
$homepage = file_get_contents($URL);
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the output from code in a file, simply just make a RESTful API call to it. This way, you can use the same code file for ajax calls, REST API, or for your internal PHP code.

It requires cURL to be installed but no output buffers or no includes, just the page executed and returned into a string.

I'll give you the code I wrote. It works with nearly every REST/web server (and even works with Equifax):

```
$return = PostRestApi($url);
```

or

```
$post = array('name' => 'Bob', 'id' => '12345');
$return = PostRestApi($url, $post, false, 6, false);
```

Here is the function:

```
/**
 * Calls a REST API and returns the result
 *
 * $loginRequest = json_encode(array("Code" => "somecode", "SecretKey" => "somekey"));
 * $result = CallRestApi("https://server.com/api/login", $loginRequest);
 *
 * @param string $url The URL for the request
 * @param array/string $data Input data to send to server; If array, use key/value pairs and if string use urlencode() for text values)
 * @param array $header_array Simple array of strings (i.e. array('Content-Type: application/json');
 * @param int $ssl_type Set preferred TLS/SSL version; Default is TLSv1.2
 * @param boolean $verify_ssl Whether to verify the SSL certificate or not
 * @param boolean $timeout_seconds Timeout in seconds; if zero then never time out
 * @return string Returned results
 */
function PostRestApi($url, $data = false, $header_array = false,
    $ssl_type = 6, $verify_ssl = true, $timeout_seconds = false) {

    // If cURL is not installed...
    if (! function_exists('curl_init')) {

        // Log and show the error
        $error = 'Function ' . __FUNCTION__ . ' Error: cURL is not installed.';
        error_log($error, 0);
        die($error);

    } else {

        // Initialize the cURL session
        $curl = curl_init($url);

        // Set the POST data
        $send = '';
        if ($data !== false) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $send = http_build_query($data);
            } else {
                $send = $data;
            }
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $send);
        }

        // Set the default header information
        $header = array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($send));
        if (is_array($header_array) && count($header_array) > 0) {
            $header = array_merge($header, $header_array);
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        // Set preferred TLS/SSL version
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, $ssl_type);

        // Verify the server's security certificate?
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, ($verify_ssl) ? 1 : 0);

        // Set the time out in seconds
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, ($timeout_seconds) ? $timeout_seconds : 0);

        // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Execute the request
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        // Close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($curl);
        unset($curl);

        // Return the results
        return $result;

    }
}
```